# Can I manually copy files to a backup drive without corrupting existing backups?

Tags: backup, external-hdd

I'm borrowing a Seagate external backup drive from a friend to backup my files while I partition my linux laptop. The external drive already contains several (macOS) backups made by Seagate software. However, it seems linux is not supported by the backup software.

So, my question is: Can I just make a new folder on the external drive, and copy my files into it as backup, without corrupting the existing backups?

My gut says no problem, but I don't want to trash my friend's files ... And my backup is just temporary for the partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to run the Software on linux -
have you looked into Wine?

[how-to-run-windows-software-on-ubuntu-with-wine](https://www.howtogeek.com/105271/how-to-run-windows-software-on-ubuntu-with-wine/)

Otherwise -
Can see it supports android -

https://www.seagate.com/gb/en/support/downloads/

is it possible you could store the macos backups on your phone?

this will give you the flexibility to either test folders on the Seagate drive while it is empty. Or to wipe completely to NTFS format to use during the partition change - then revert after with the software again.